# How to run multiple gremlin queries as a single transaction?

Tags: go, transactions, gremlin

I am wondering how to execute multiple queries in one transaction in go language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883983/how-to-run-multiple-gremlin-commands-as-a-single-transaction Does this help i have not used it with go

Comment: which go client are you using?